# sails js running testProjects issue in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I am new to nodejs and after installing sails when i try to run it, using command **sails lift**, it gives me below error. Need help to resolve it.

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/lodash/index.js:692
  function runInContext(context) {
                   ^
  illegal access
```

Comment: I hope the answer below continues to work. If you would like an additional resource, here is a chat room for sails.js, node.js, and waterline questions. https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was an issue with the version of node i was using **v0.11.13**. I have changed the version and it started working.